# How to share program that uses private API key without sharing the key?

Tags: api

Currently working on a python project, and am trying to get it usable enough to the point where I could share it with other people on platforms like reddit or github. However, I can't go sharing around the API. Is there any way to include the API key but hide it somehow so it is simultaneously usable and still hidden from any users who download my repository?

Comment: Look up ENV files and how to use them. Theyre local files that allow you to specify things like THIS_API = 'your_api_key' and then you just call THIS_API whenever you want to access it in your code.

Comment: Is that something I can setup so that it's sharable and private? As in, is there a way to make it so if someone who downloads the repository can use the API key without being able to know what that key actually is?

Comment: No, you cant have it both ways( if you can, please enlighten me). Also, API keys are not supposed to be shared. So either keep it public (which is not common) or keep it as an ENV_variable. I'd say that if anyone is about to download your repo and work with it, getting a hold of an API key shouldn't be that much of a problem. Just remember that if you go the ENV route, you need to use a file named '.gitignore' in your rootdirectory with `.env` to make sure that it's not added to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to have an API key be shared so it's both usable and private. If you can't share the API, then you'll just have to keep it to yourself.